# Can't install Windows 8?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Okay, so this is the first time ever that I install a non-Mac operating system. But it went like this:

First, I downloaded the drivers to a 4GB USB stick. Then, I created a 300GB partition on my hard drive. I put my SuperDrive with my Windows 8 installation CD into my computer and booted, I went through the installation process and then it said that something was wrong with my hard drive format.

I then formated it into a NTSF and booted again, upon which it complained about that my hard drive is MBR and that it needs to be GPT, so I just decided I will continue tomorrow and format my drive again through the installation CD.

So, today I tried booting my computer today again, but on the first step the installation program just said that it can't find my drivers, so I restarted into OS X and redownloaded the drivers and tried again, same thing. I tried changing my USB and SuperDrive from USB-2 to USB-3 but it didn't work either.

Now when I boot, it just says:

> non system disk
>
> press any key to reboot

And I have tried to reboot 3 times but I still just get that message. Is it supposed to be this complicated to install Windows? What can I do? I just want to play a game.

Comment: Any reason you did not use and follow the instructions from the boot camp app.

Comment: That's what I did, what makes you think I didn't?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I followed it all up on the way to where it said that the drive needs to be NTFS. I tried redoing it all again today but it still just tells me that it is not a NTFS. It's as far as I can come using only BootCamp.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstand ting. Just the way you wrote your question made me believe you did it manually. Could you use "diskutil list" in Terminal so we can see how your HD looks like.

Comment: What is the model of your Mac? The proper procedure does depend on this. Also, do you know if your version of windows is 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootcamp app will walk you through creating the install media from your ISO **and** the proper partitioning. No need to create one manually.

I would delete that partition you made, expand your Mac volume back into the open space and then recreate the USB stick using BootCamp. It should ask for an ISO of the Windows install media and use the drivers in the App to slipstream the driver files into the installation media. You'll need a 4GB USB stick (minimum, bigger is fine). Creating the install USB stick takes a while (30-40 minutes in some cases) then run bootcamp and follow the prompts.

It will give you a GUI for resizing your Mac partition. It will then properly format it and put the necessary Windows boot files on the drive and then boot you into the Windows installer.

If you follow those instructions it should all work for you fine, **unless** there is already a non-standard partition arrangement on the drive.

Comment: That's what I've done, and it just tells me that the drive has to be in NTFS. But I am using a Windows-8 CD and not an ISO.

Comment: Very strange. I would try it with an ISO and make a bootable USB key. Disk utility will make an ISO out of the Windows installer media. Once that is done run through bootcamp again and tell it to create the install media from your DMG file. If it doesn't see the DMG file change the file extension to ISO.